# New Office 2013 Javascript API limitations

Tags: javascript, vba, ms-office

I've looked at the documentation and it appears the new javascript "app" api is missing alot of functionality that is present in VBA.  For instance, the majority of cell manipulation and formatting.  Or is it?  I'm not a javascript expert so maybe I'm missing something.  But based on what I see this api would not be able to accomplish any mildly involved line of business automation.  I've scoured the net and haven't found any apps that show otherwise. I've only found the standard "plug Bing into excel" type apps.

Am I missing something?

If I'm not, anybody know how aggressively MS is planning on adding to this api in the future?

Comment: Don't hold your breath. Most likely, it will take another cycle

Comment: Bingo, I thought so. Coz Microsoft likes to give lot of pain to programmers in the first build. Remember how the chart object was not exposed in PowerPoint and in Word until SP2 hit the market in office 2007? I almost had killed myself coz I had to change chart colors in PowerPoint using OpenXML. I thought to wait this time until they have a stable release, and seems I was right :)

Comment: There's an overview [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/06/18/roadmap-for-apps-for-office-vsto-and-vba.aspx) but zero details on when specific features will be available. It's a fairly recent blog post (June 2013) so it might be worth asking in the comments for more details from the author @Michael Zlatkovsky

Comment: Hi, did you get more information when a more complete JS api will be available?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a support question about Microsoft's products; not a programming issue.

Answer (score 1):

With the release of Office 2013 SP1, there is the ability to manipulate formatting:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535872(v=office.1501401).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535872%28v=office.1501401%29.aspx)

Hopefully that will handle most of the use cases you're concerned with.